# API route not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I have an API in my code with a route prefix but when I try to hit it, I get a 404. This is my code:

```
namespace MyProject.Authentication.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/user")]
    public class MyUserController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly IMyDomainService _myDomainService;

        public MyUserController()
        {
            _myDomainService = new MyDomainService();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [HttpRoute("get/test")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Test()
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "test success");
        }
    }
}
```

when I try to hit mysite.com/api/user/get/test I get a 404.

I checked AttributeRoutingHttpConfig.cs and this is what looks like, same as I have in other projects where the APIs work fine:

```
public static class AttributeRoutingHttpConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(HttpRouteCollection routes)
    {
        // See http://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting/wiki for more options.
        // To debug routes locally using the built in ASP.NET development server, go to /routes.axd

        routes.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    }

    public static void Start()
    {
        RegisterRoutes(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes);
    }
}
```

edit: this is in ASP.NET 4.5

Comment: I'm curious about this: `[HttpRoute("get/test")]`. Perhaps I'm not familiar with that attribute, but I would expect it to be `[Route("get/test")]`.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure it should not be using the `RouteAttribute` to decorate the action rather than `HttpRouteAttribute`, you've not created that by using the intellisense to create a class with the name `HttpRouteAttribute` accidentally have you?